# How do I bind keys using general.el alongside evil?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, use-package

My goal is to bind `SPC SPC` to `counsel-M-x`.
I've tried using this snippet from this [post](https://sam217pa.github.io/2016/08/30/how-to-make-your-own-spacemacs/)

```
(use-package general
 :ensure t
 :config
 (general-evil-setup t)
 (general-define-key
  :states '(normal visual insert emacs)
  :prefix "SPC"
  "SPC" '(counsel-M-x :which-key "M-x")
   )
  )
```

I don't see any errors when I evaluate this snippet but it's not taking an effect, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to do this instead:

```
(general-define-key
 :keymaps 'normal
 :prefix "SPC"
 "SPC" '(counsel-M-x :which-key "M-x"))
```

You generally want to use `:keymaps` for the global evil state keymaps. See the readme for more details. Please make an issue on the general.el repository if you have further questions.